# How to join a file name listing into a single line?

Tags: powershell

I want to join the listing of file names from `ls` using a standard `ls` filter (e.g., `ls a*.txt`) so that the result is a single line with each file name separated by a space. For example,

```
a1.txt a2.txt a3.txt
```

How can I achieve this in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are quiet a few ways to do this. On PowerShell V3 or higher (for -join IIRC) you can do this:

```
"$(ls a*.txt -name)"
```

Or

```
(ls a*.txt -Name) -join ' '
```

Comment: If you're still on PowerShell v2, you can do this:

    (ls 1*.txt | Select -exp Name) -join ' '